# Change button when textarea is dirty

Tags: html, css, angularjs

When I edit "textarea" I want my button to change its color(or being able to receive other orders from this are). Is it pure CSS or is there something to modify in my code too?  I can't find any refereces to this on my own.

so when "form" is dirty, button shall change color-  ( I am not capable of classes, or CSS )

here my **HTML:**

```
<form name="formSignature" class="">
    <div>
      <i> Persönliche Signatur </i><br/>
      <textarea rows="5" cols="40" ng-model="newAccountSig" ng-trim="false" placeholder="{{user.signature}}">
      </textarea>
    </div>
    <div ng-hide="permissionExists('sign_change_global')">
    <i> Zweites Beispiel</i><br/>
    <textarea ng-readonly="true" rows="5" cols="40" ng-model="newCustomerSig" ng-trim="false" placeholder="{{user.customer.signature}}">
    </textarea>
    </div>

    <div ng-show="permissionExists('sign_change_global')">
      <i> Show this, when "sign_change_global" is in LIST</i><br/>
      <textarea rows="5" cols="40" ng-model="newCustomerSig" ng-trim="false" placeholder="{{user.customer.signature}}"></textarea>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Shall affect button outside of "form":

```
  <button type="submit" style="text-align:right; float:right"
           class="button green-button"
           ng-click="saveSignature()">Save</button>
```

I borderd the form, as a little hint for me.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try to add a name to your textareas, example :

```
<textarea rows="5" name="id1" cols="40" ng-model="newAccountSig" ng-trim="false" placeholder="{{user.signature}}">
  </textarea>
```

and put it in your button

```
ng-class="{' button green-button' : formSignature.id1.$pristine && formSignature.id2.$pristine && formSignature.id3.$pristine, 'button red-button' : !formSignature.id1.$pristine || !formSignature.id2.$pristine || !formSignature.id3.$pristine}"
```

Comment: I may be wrong but shouldn't `id1` be set to `name` or is it really `id`? I can't test at the moment but I thought I remembered using the `name` attr.

Comment: yes you are right, it's name instead of id , i change it